# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with import statement

Tags: javascript

In the following code:

```
ROOTNS.ui.components.orgChart = (function () {

    import PubSub from 'pubsub-js'

})();
```

I get the runtime error on the import statement of:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

My app is based on Chromium version 66, which supports the import statement, so what is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: `import` needs to be at the top of your unit.

Comment: But that would place it outside of the closure. Is that not a problem if I have multiple modules in my app that also use the same import statement?

Comment: As far as I know, unless your using a dynamic import, you need your imports at the top of the unit.  Why does `PubSub` need to be inside the closure.?

Comment: @AndroidDev What do you mean by "multiple modules in the app"? There is only one module per file.

Comment: @Bergi I have several files similar to this one and they must all import the same library (PubSub), so will this not be a conflict if they are imported multiple times?

Comment: It will only get imported once, that's what module loaders job is.

Comment: @AndroidDev No, there's no conflict, each module has its own scope. You don't need IIFEs when using ES6 modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports must be at the top of your script before any other code. ES6 modules don't work like other module systems where you can load modules conditionally.

```
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js'

ROOTNS.ui.components.orgChart = (function () {

// other code 

})();
```